# One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dll

I have an MVC3 project with Razor Generator view engine installed.
But I receive the following error when I try to compile any of the View files
(this occurs in all my Views)

"Error: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?"

As a result of this, the helper methods using lambda syntax cannot be used (throwing additional errors), as well as the dynamic types like ViewBag.

I have already manually added both of those References (Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll) into the project. They were already there to start with, but I removed them, and then re-added them with 4.0.0.0 versions.

I have also made sure that each of those references have "Copy Local=True"

Any ideas as to why this error will not go away?

Please let me know if you would like to look at my Web.Config file to check if 
the assemblies are added in correctly. I will be glad to provide that if it is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Error occurs on the ViewBag.Title line:
@model vm_Admin
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
 }
<div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix">

Answer (score 0):

got to config file and change

> < compilation debug="true"> TO < compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> in the system.web section

change

> < providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="what ever you have over here" />  to < providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />  on config file's compilers section

finally  add  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()); to the Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs.

if this didn't work let me know let s try alternative way.